# Parameters using NSMutableRequest and Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, alamofire

I'm trying to make a request to my API on an app in swift using AlamoFire. I need to use so custom headers so I opted to use the NSURLRequest approach, here is my code:

```
let URL = NSURL(string: "\(APIUrl)/sessions")!
let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let parameters = ["oauth_token": OAuthToken]
var JSONSerializationError: NSError? = nil

mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: nil, error: &JSONSerializationError)
mutableURLRequest.addHeadersInDictionary(self.defaultHeaders)

Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest)
         .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
         .responseJSON { [weak self] request, response, JSON, error in
             println(request.description)
             if let strongSelf = self, response = response {
                 if error == nil {
                     let jsonResult = JSON as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                     strongSelf.setAuthToken(jsonResult[JsonConstants.AuthToken] as! String)
                     strongSelf.defaultHeaders["Authorization"] = "Token token=\(strongSelf.authToken()!)"
                     success?()
                 } else {
                     println("Failed with \(response.statusCode)")
                     println(error!)
                     failure?()
                 }
             } else  {
                 println(error!)
                 failure?()
             }
     }
```

I receive the request perfectly on my API, but on my logs I see that the parameters sent where not exactly the ones I sent:

```
Parameters: {"oauth_token"=>"token", "session"=>{"oauth_token"=>"token"}}
```

Is there any reason why AlamoFire is adding a `session : []` parameter to my HTTP Body? and is there a way to clean those parameters just to send the required information to the server, or at least remove the `oauth_token` that's outside the session parameter?

Also if I sent the request without adding the `HTTPBody` I will receive on my server just the `session` parameter empty:

```
Parameters: {"session"=>{}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That `session` parameter is not being appended by Alamofire. You must be adding it somewhere in your logic that is not shown in your example. Additionally, what does your `addHeadersInDictionary` method doing?

Comment: That's the only piece of code that is used to create a network request. That code is actually on it's own method and it's called from the controller when a user taps a button... `addHeadersInDictionary` does `self.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: header)` for a dictionary with values for `Accept` and `Content-Type`.

Comment: You should take a look at the cURL output from `debugPrintln(request)` and see if that sheds any light.